# Website shows error warning , fatal error

Tags: wordpress

Website http://beststoves.net/ shows error

> Warning: require_once(/homepages/11/d607525959/htdocs/clickandbuilds/BeststovesNet/wp-includes/cache.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /homepages/11/d607525959/htdocs/clickandbuilds/BeststovesNet/wp-includes/load.php on line 503
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/homepages/11/d607525959/htdocs/clickandbuilds/BeststovesNet/wp-includes/cache.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php5.5') in /homepages/11/d607525959/htdocs/clickandbuilds/BeststovesNet/wp-includes/load.php on line 503

Web provider has no backup functions. Login area of wp blogin not accessible anymore.

Comment: Try [reinstalling WordPress](https://kinsta.com/blog/reinstall-wordpress/) either via WP-CLI or via FTP.

Comment: replace wp-includes folder via FTP and it should work.